# The class is set to the wrong element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a card game and need to find a pair. I almost made it. But there's a problem.
Card names are loaded from js and shuffled.
I sort through them through forEach. The cards are stored in an array. And let's say when I click on the last square, it shows me that it has id 7. Now if I click on the first one in the script
cards[srav[index].id].classList.add('none') will set the class to the wrong element, since querySelectorAll always counts from zero. How can I make sure that the necessary id is cleared for me?

[image]
But clear this
[image]

```js
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
// let id = document.getElementById('id')

let object = [{
    name: 'JavaScript',
    id: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'JavaScript',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Java',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Java',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'C++',
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'C++',
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'C#',
    id: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'C#',
    id: 7
  },
]
object.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

let srav = []

cards.forEach((element, i) => {
  cards[i].innerHTML = object[i].name
  cards[i].classList.add('active')
})

cards.forEach((element, i) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cards[i].classList.remove('active')
    srav.push(object[i])
    console.log(element)
    if (srav.length == 2) {

      if (srav[0].name == srav[1].name) {
        console.log('вы выбрали карточки где именя одинаковы')
        for (let index = 0; index < srav.length; index++) {
          cards[srav[index].id].classList.add('none')

        }
      } else {
        console.log('Тут нет карт с одинаковыми именами')
        console.log(srav[0].id)
        console.log(srav[1].id)

      }
    }
    // console.log(srav.length)
  })
})
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background: transparent;
}

.card.active {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"> </div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few improvements. Comments in code.

```js
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
// let id = document.getElementById('id')

let object = [{
    name: 'JavaScript',
    id: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'JavaScript',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Java',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Java',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'C++',
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'C++',
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'C#',
    id: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'C#',
    id: 7
  },
]

// recommened: better shuffle algorithm
object.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);


let srav = []

cards.forEach((element, i) => {
  cards[i].innerHTML = object[i].name
  cards[i].id = object[i].id // <--- or another data-attribute
  cards[i].classList.add('active')
})

// convert to array so we can `find`
cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(cards)

cards.forEach((element, i) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element.classList.remove('active')

    srav.push(object[i])
    if (srav.length == 2) {

      // added condition that shouldn't be same card twice
      if (srav[0].name == srav[1].name && srav[0].id !== srav[1].id) {

        // yes
        console.log('вы выбрали карточки где именя одинаковы')
        
        // array pop so srav would get back to []
        while (srav.length) {
          var id = srav.pop().id;
          cards.find(item => item.id == id).classList.add('none')
        }
      } else {

        // not
        console.log('Тут нет карт с одинаковыми именами')
        
        // array pop so srav would get back to []
        while (srav.length) {
          var id = srav.pop().id;
          cards.find(item => item.id == id).classList.add('active')
        }
      }
    }

  })
})
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background: yellow;
}

.card.active {
  background: red;
}

.card.none {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```